# Make last HTTP request when user shuts down Ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Is there a way to make a last HTTP request (logout for example) in an Ionic/Cordova app when the user closes the app?

I know it can be done if the app goes into background with [event pause](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/events/events.pause.html), but can it be done when the app is shut down by the user?

Apparently Cordova's event pause doesn't work well on iOS.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @felipeclopes no, I think to remember there was a plugin or some method (it was a long time ago) for running code when the OS kills the app, but it never worked and that requirement had to be scrapped. That was with Ionic 1, I don't know how current versions of Ionic (or mobile OS's) work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option you have is to experiment with the **beforeunload** (`window.onbeforeunload`) and **unload** (`window.onunload`) events on the various platforms you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get through Ionic & Cordova without any extras is

```
// Cordova app enter foreground
$ionicPlatform.on('resume', function() {

});

// Cordova app enter background event
$ionicPlatform.on('pause', function() {

});
```

There is, however, a plugin which supposedly sets an event listener that runs when the cordova activity stops, `cordova-plugin-ondestroy` : https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-ondestroy

I have not tested, but it may be a solution for you.